# Auto Mapper FromBase64String to ToBase64String more concise way

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-6.0

I have a below `MappingProfile`. It is working fine. But do you know how to write it in a single line or a more concise manner?

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ExpenseDto, Expense>().ForMember(expense => expense.Image,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(expenseDto => Convert.FromBase64String(expenseDto.Image)));

            CreateMap<Expense, ExpenseDto>().ForMember(expenseDto => expenseDto.Image,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(expense => Convert.ToBase64String(expense.Image)));
   
        }
    }
```

*Expense Entity*

```
public class Expense
    {
       public byte[]? Image { get; set; }
    }
```

*Expense Dto*

```
public record ExpenseDto
{
   public string? Image { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: I think that can be impossible because how Automapper will know when to convert string to string and when string to base64...

Comment: This isn't a mapping. This is serialization from binary to string with a specific encoding. AutoMapper was built to handle straightforward mappings, not act as a transformation library. Check [Automapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/). Besides, what you want to do is what a JSON serializer would do with a DTO *after* it was transformed by Automapper. Why is Automapper to do this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Why is Automapper to do this?` It would be great if you'll show me how to do this without Automapper? I have put my `entity` and `dto` for your reference. If you'll need any other info please let me know.

Comment: You can specify [a custom converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) from `byte[]` to `string` and use it for such fields. What I asked though is why *your code* is doing this instead of letting the serializer do it. BASE64 is used when making or returning HTTP results, or serializing to files. It's not needed in databases

Comment: You can create a custom type converter from `byte[]` to `string` and vice versa. And then you can remove those resolvers.

Comment: This conversion will cause performance issues, especially under load. Performing the conversion like this allocates a big string that needs to be garbage-collected. The serializer on the other hand would right the converted characters directly to the output stream.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok sure. I'll see your link and try that. If I'll have any issues I'll create a new question for that. Thanks!